# Find the company that has the smallest payroll

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hi i have the following database scheema.

```
employee (employee-name, street, city)
works (employee-name, company-name, salary)
company (company-name, city)
manages (employee-name, manager-name)
```

I need to find Find the company that has the smallest payroll.

I have written the following query but my trainer tells me its wrong.

```
SELECT company-name
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name
HAVING sum(salary) < ( SELECT sum(salary)
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name)
```

Comment: no i am not suppossed to execute it on a db just write a query like dat and d trainner tells me whether its wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery

```
SELECT company-name, sum(salary)
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name
```

will give you the cumulative salaries (payrolls) for each company.
If you order those data in ascending order, the first record will be the company with the smallest payroll.

```
SELECT company-name, sum(salary)
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name
ORDER BY sum(salary)
```

You can than use MySQL's [LIMIT](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-to-use-LIMIT-clause-in-MySQL) clause to restrict that recordset just to a single record, using

```
SELECT company-name, sum(salary)
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name
ORDER BY sum(salary)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a further hint. The `<` is what's wrong (think carefully about what the subquery returns).

Comment: the sub query returns the sum of salaries of a company. I am new to sql so not much of an idea...

Answer (score 0):

we can use `< All` in this case?

e.g. :

```
SELECT company-name
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name
HAVING sum(salary) < ALL( SELECT sum(salary)
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it as follows:

```
SELECT company_name, SUM (salary) AS lowest_payroll
    FROM works
GROUP BY company_name
  HAVING SUM (salary) = (SELECT MIN (payrl)     AS low_payroll
                           FROM (  SELECT company_name, SUM (salary) payrl
                                     FROM works
                                 GROUP BY company_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT company-name
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name
HAVING sum(salary) < ( SELECT sum(salary)
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name)
```

You have to change < to <= all and not < all

```sql
SELECT company-name
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name
HAVING sum(salary) <= all ( SELECT sum(salary)
FROM works
GROUP BY company-name)
```

Because the minimum sum(salary) should be equated to true, example

```sql
HAVING 590000 <= all (750000 , 590000 , 620000)
```

Should return true in this case as 590000 when compared with 590000 in () should return true i.e. 590000 <= 590000 -> true, where as 590000 < 590000 -> false so you wouldn't get any output so correct < all to <= all.